# how to get key from object to object over looping using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```js
const jsondata = {
  "Automobile Assembler": {
    "0": "Sazgar Engineering Works Ltd: 147.25",
    "1": "Pak Suzuki Motor Co. Ltd: 165.07",
    "2": "Millat Tractors Ltd: 724.80",
    "3": "Indus Motor Company Ltd: 956.42",
    "4": "Hinopak Motors Ltd: 360.00",
    "5": "Honda Atlas Cars(Pakistan) Ltd: 198.07",
    "6": "Ghandhara Nissan Ltd:64.93",
    "7": "Ghandhara Industries Ltd: 120.40", 
    "8": "Ghani Automobile Industries Ltd: 5.80",
    "9": "Dewan Farooque Motors Ltd: 4.32",
    "10": "Atlas Honda Ltd: 392.50",
    "11": "Al - Ghazi Tractors Ltd:353.21"
  },
  "Automobile Parts & Accessories": {
    "12": "Loads Limited: 15.00",
    "13": "Thal Ltd:335.00",
    "14": "The General Tyre & Rubber Company Ltd: 60.12",
    "15": "Exide Pakistan Ltd:283.16",
    "16": "Baluchistan Wheels Ltd: 62.00",
    "17": "Bela Automotives Ltd: 1.30",
    "18": "Atlas BatteryLtd: 174.02",
    "19": "Dewan Automotive Engineering Ltd: 3.26",
    "20": "Agriauto Industries Ltd: 187.79"
  }
}


Object.keys(jsondata).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  delete (key)
})
```

I run through loop getting answer Automobile Assembler & Automobile Parts & Accessories
I want to get key 0,1,2,3,4 and remove the key in this object

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, iterate over your `jsondata` and after that find keys from nested objects and delete those keys in this way:

```js
jsondata = {
    "Automobile Assembler": {
        "0": "Sazgar Engineering Works Ltd: 147.25",
        "1": "Pak Suzuki Motor Co. Ltd: 165.07",
        "2": "Millat Tractors Ltd: 724.80",
        "3": "Indus Motor Company Ltd: 956.42",
        "4": "Hinopak Motors Ltd: 360.00",
        "5": "Honda Atlas Cars (Pakistan) Ltd: 198.07",
        "6": "Ghandhara Nissan Ltd: 64.93",
        "7": "Ghandhara Industries Ltd: 120.40",
        "8": "Ghani Automobile Industries Ltd: 5.80",
        "9": "Dewan Farooque Motors Ltd: 4.32",
        "10": "Atlas Honda Ltd: 392.50",
        "11": "Al-Ghazi Tractors Ltd: 353.21"
    },
    "Automobile Parts & Accessories": {
        "12": "Loads Limited: 15.00",
        "13": "Thal Ltd: 335.00",
        "14": "The General Tyre & Rubber Company Ltd: 60.12",
        "15": "Exide Pakistan Ltd: 283.16",
        "16": "Baluchistan Wheels Ltd: 62.00",
        "17": "Bela Automotives Ltd: 1.30",
        "18": "Atlas Battery Ltd: 174.02",
        "19": "Dewan Automotive Engineering Ltd: 3.26",
        "20": "Agriauto Industries Ltd: 187.79"
    }
}

let entries = Object.entries(jsondata);

entries.forEach(([prop, val]) => {

    Object.keys(val).forEach((key) => {

        if (key == 0 || key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3 || key == 4) {
            delete (jsondata[prop][key]);
        }

    })
});

// After deleting keys "0", "1", "2", "3" and "4", your jsondata will be like this
console.log(jsondata);
```

Comment: I want to delete the only key indexes not value your code key indexes and value both deleted in JSON data object I want only 0,1,2,3,4...only key, not value like "Automobile Assembler": { "Sazgar Engineering Works Ltd: 147.25", "Pak Suzuki Motor Co. Ltd: 165.07", "Millat Tractors Ltd: 724.80", "Indus Motor Company Ltd: 956.42", "Hinopak Motors Ltd: 360.00", }